# Searching documents using ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with one to many relationship (arrays). I want to search documents based on the following criteria.

How can I find all documents where "acctType" = "SAVINGS" and the **latest** "event" from the "events" array (based on eventId) has "eventCode" = "CREDIT" and evenDate <= "04-18-2023"? My challenge is to search only the latest element from an array to meet the criteria. The "events" array is always sorted based on the "eventId". So the first element in the array will have the highest eventId, and the search should only include the first element.

```
[
  {
    "acctId": 1234,
    "acctType": "SAVINGS",
    "events": [
      {
        "eventId": 5,
        "eventCode": "UPDATE-PROFILE",
        "eventDate": "04-14-2023"
      },
      {
        "eventId": 3,
        "eventCode": "TRANSFER-FUND",
        "eventDate": "04-03-2023"
      },
      {
        "eventId": 2,
        "eventCode": "CREDIT",
        "eventDate": "04-01-2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "acctId": 4567,
    "acctType": "MONEY-MARKET",
    "events": [
      {
        "eventId": 102,
        "eventCode": "UPDATE-PROFILE",
        "eventDate": "04-14-2022"
      },
      {
        "eventId": 100
        "eventCode": "TRANSFER-FUND",
        "eventDate": "04-12-2023"
      },
      {
        "eventId": 99,
        "eventCode": "CREDIT",
        "eventDate": "04-10-2023"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You are probably not deconstructing your information properly, and you should have a document for each event that contains all the action information. You can also experiment with [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#:~:text=The%20nested%20type%20is%20a,queried%20independently%20of%20each%20other to query nested documents independently of each other).